# php исключить ошибку если параметр не существует

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, html5

код работает, но если вдруг значение ID пусто, или не существует сам ID то php возвращает ошибку, нужно задать условие что если ID пуст или не существует - завершить выполнение функции

```html
<?php
function printstr($text)
{ global $decoded;
  echo('  <div class="row"><div class="col-md-1"></div><div class="col-md-2 headings">');
  echo($text);
  echo('</div><div class="col-md-5 content">');
  echo($decoded->id);
  echo('</div>');
}

$url = "https://***";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$decoded = json_decode($content);
printstr("id");
?>
```

Comment: `isset()` вам в помощь.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (empty($decoded->id)) {
    return;
}
```

`isset()` тут не нужен потому, что это функциональность выполняет `empty()`

Answer (score 1):

> нужно задать условие что если ID пуст или не существует - завершить выполнение функции

```
if (!isset($decoded->id) || empty($decoded->id)) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, а почему если в функцию прописать echo($decoded->fio->name); всё работает, а если вызвать функцию с параметрами printstr("fio->name"); возникает ошибка Notice: Undefined property: stdClass:

Comment: @NormalArs Потому что в `printstr("fio->name");` вы пытаетесь обратиться к свойству неизвестного обьекта. Правильнее будет `printstr($decoded->fio->name);`